# "Background Items Added" appears for App that I uninstalled, would like to remove it

Tags: notifications, multitasking, macos

In my notification bar I can't seem to get rid of these pesky pop-ups. I uninstalled the "Razer USA Ltd." app, but apparently some process still is running in the background. When I go to the Login Items Settings, you can see in the screenshot below Razer is disabled

[image: Razer notifications in notification bar]

[image: login items setting screen with Razer disabled]

Comment: Are you sure you have removed all of it? Have you restarted since you removed it? I would look in /Library/LaunchAgents and /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: I did find two files there from Razer that I deleted. I restarted and I think the issue has gone away! Many Thanks, can I promote your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would look in `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

Delete any files there and restart.